# android no applications can perform this action error

Tags: android, eclipse, file-upload, storage

So I'm having a problem when trying to choose a file from the storage in my android app. I'm using the Emulator to try this out but when pressing the button I get **No app can perfrom this action**. I have no idea why so I need some help.

Code:

So please help me out guys! Thanks!

Comment: You don't have an app which accepts that intent. Make your own file opener.

Comment: What makes you think that `file/*` is a valid MIME type?

Comment: I changed the MIME type to * / * and now it works fine. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file/*` is not a valid MIME type so android cannot find a suitable application to handle your Intent. Use a proper MIME type for the file you'd like to open.